# Page Navigation Script not fully working in Blogger

Tags: javascript, blogger

I picked up this great javascript from MS-Potilas of http://yabtb.blogspot.com/ which gives me my next and previous blog titles appended to the prev and next icons by calling the title information from the blog feed.  And if that somehow fails, it has a backup, which is to pull the information off the urls and turn that into the title in its PseudoTitle mode.

Thing is, it only works for about the newest half of my blog posts.  After that, it switches into PseduoTitle mode.

Here's what I don't understand.  It's supposed to work for 500 posts.  My site only has 350+.  So why does it seem to work properly for only the newest 100+ posts?

Also, is there something I can do so that I can increase the number of posts that this script will work for after I go past 500 posts?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Here's the script;

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
// Post titles to Older Post and Newer Post links (without stats skew)
// by MS-potilas 2012. See http://yabtb.blogspot.com/
//<![CDATA[
var urlToNavTitle = {};
function getTitlesForNav(json) {
  for(var i=0 ; i < json.feed.entry.length ; i++) {
    var entry = json.feed.entry[i];
    var href = "";
    for (var k=0; k<entry.link.length; k++) {
      if (entry.link[k].rel == 'alternate') {
        href = entry.link[k].href;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(href!="") urlToNavTitle[href]=entry.title.$t;
  }
}
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="//'+window.location.hostname+'/feeds/posts/summary?redirect=false&max-results=500&alt=json-in-script&callback=getTitlesForNav"/>');
function urlToPseudoTitle(href) {
  var title=href.match(/\/([^\/_]+)(_.*)?\.html/);
  if(title) {
    title=title[1].replace(/-/g," ");
    title=title[0].toUpperCase() + title.slice(1);
    if(title.length > 28) title=title.replace(/ [^ ]+$/, "...")
  }
  return title;
}
$(window).load(function() {
 window.setTimeout(function() {
  var href = $("a.blog-pager-newer-link").attr("href");
  if(href) {
    href = href.replace(/\http\:[^/]+\//, "https");
    var title=urlToNavTitle[href];
    if(!title) title=urlToPseudoTitle(href);
    if(title) $("a.blog-pager-newer-link").html("&lt;&lt; Newer<br />" + title); 
  }
  href = $("a.blog-pager-older-link").attr("href"); 
  if(href) {
    href = href.replace(/\http\:[^/]+\//, "https");
    var title=urlToNavTitle[href];
    if(!title) title=urlToPseudoTitle(href);
    if(title) $("a.blog-pager-older-link").html("Older &gt;&gt;<br />" + title);
  }
 }, 500);
});
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems I managed to figure it out.

Apparently, even though the script says max-results=500, the script is really only pulling 150 posts.  I don't know why that is.

So I just added more retrieval scripts like this to cover the rest.

```
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="//'+window.location.hostname+'/feeds/posts/summary?redirect=false&max-results=150&start-index=151&alt=json-in-script&callback=getTitlesForNav"/>');
function urlToPseudoTitle(href) {
  var title=href.match(/\/([^\/_]+)(_.*)?\.html/);
  if(title) {
    title=title[1].replace(/-/g," ");
    title=title[0].toUpperCase() + title.slice(1);
    if(title.length > 28) title=title.replace(/ [^ ]+$/, "...")
  }
  return title;
}
```

Many thanks to Adam over at http://too-clever-by-half.blogspot.com/ for providing the solution to the &start-index=151 extension.